# Powershell: Filter the contents of a file by an array of strings

Tags: powershell

Riddle me this:

I have a text file of data.  I want to read it in, and only output lines that contain any string that is found in an array of search terms.

If I were looking for just one string, I would do something like this:

```
get-content afile | where { $_.Contains("TextI'mLookingFor") } | out-file FilteredContent.txt
```

Now, I just need for "TextI'mLookingFor" to be an array of strings, where if $_ contains any string in the array, it is passed down the pipe to out-file.

How would I do that (and BTW, I'm a c# programmer hacking this powershell script, so if there is a better way to do my match above than using .Contains(), clue me in!)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try `Select-String` . It allows an array of patterns. Ex:

```
$p = @("this","is","a test")
Get-Content '.\New Text Document.txt' | Select-String -Pattern $p -SimpleMatch | Set-Content FilteredContent.txt
```

Notice that I use `-SimpleMatch` so that `Select-String` ignores special regex-characters. If you want regex in your patterns, just remove that.

For a single pattern I would probably use this, but you have to escape regex characters in the pattern:

```
Get-Content '.\New Text Document.txt' | ? { $_ -match "a test" }
```

`Select-String` is a great cmdlet for single patterns too, it's just a few characters longer to write ^^

Answer (score 5):

Any help?

```
$a_Search = @(
    "TextI'mLookingFor",
    "OtherTextI'mLookingFor",
    "MoreTextI'mLookingFor"
    )


[regex] $a_regex = ‘(‘ + (($a_Search |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)’

(get-content afile) -match $a_regex
```

Comment: Select string is probably a better choice, especially for file data.

Comment: Just ran a quick test, and -match works better for large numbers of reps (about 15x faster than select-string).

Comment: Thanks for the regex variation +1.  I gave the answer to the select-string response because of the simplicity.

Comment: Unless I was doing it inside a very busy loop I would, too. :)

Answer (score 3):

without regex and with spaces possible:

```
$array = @("foo", "bar", "hello world")
get-content afile | where { foreach($item in $array) { $_.contains($item) } } > FilteredContent.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = @("foo","bar","baz")
findstr ($a -join " ") afile > FilteredContent.txt
```